# Castle Windsor: PerWebRequest in controller

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, perwebrequest

I am using Castle Windsor in MVC application and i have got this problem:

I have `IUnitOfWorkProvider` dependency which I want to have `PerWebRequest` lifestyle.

In Controller I have these two dependecies:

```cs
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public UserController(IUnitOfWorkProvider unitOfWorkProvider,
                          IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider)
    {
        this.unitOfWorkProvider = unitOfWorkProvider;
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }
    ...
}
```

`AuthenticationProvider` has the same dependency (`IUnitOfWorkProvider`)

```cs
public class AuthenticationProvider : IAuthenticationProvider
{
    public AuthenticationProvider(IUnitOfWorkProvider unitOfWorkProvider)
    {
        this.unitOfWorkProvider = unitOfWorkProvider;
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that the "two" `UnitOfWorkProvider`s (in the controller and in `AuthenticationProvider`) **are not the same** which I would expect them to be.

`IAuthenticationProvider`,`AuthenticationProvider` and its registration are in different project (Windows Library).

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWorkProvider>()
                            .ImplementedBy<UnitOfWorkProvider>()
                            .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

`LifestylePerThread` does not work with the **same error**.

**When I set `LifestyleSignleton` it works fine.**

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: i don't quite get what's the actual problem

Comment: @maxlego: I have changed the description to be more understandable, hope that is better

Comment: what's IAuthenticationProvider lifestyle?

Comment: IAuthenticationProvider has a singleton lifestyle. How could I do such a silly mistake! Thank for help. That was really a professional blindness :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that IAuthenticationProvider had singleton lifestyle. I have changed it to PerWebRequest as well and now it works fine.